# How to change character time to numeric time in R

Tags: r

I have a character variable like this:

```
"1h 3m 6s
 0h 13m 30s
 0h 15m 12s"
```

The desired output is converting to numeric seconds. What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert the single string into substring at the space before the hour (using `strsplit`), replace the 'h', 'm', 's' with 3600, 60, and 1 correspondingly, and do an evaluation to get the output as seconds

```
library(gsubfn)     
str2 <- strsplit(str1, "\\s(?=\\d+h)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```

If the string separation is newline, then do

```
str2 <- strsplit(str1, "\n\\s")[[1]]
```

Use `gsubfn` to replace the 'h', 'm', 's' values and evaluate later

```
unname(sapply(gsubfn("([a-z]+)", list(h = " * 3600", m = " * 60", s = " * 1"), 
        gsub(" ", " + ", str2)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
#[1] 3786  810  912
```

---

If we are using `lubridate` the `period_to_seconds` can be used after splitting the string and converting it to a `Period` class with `as.period`

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(as.period(toupper(str2)))
#[1] 3786  810  912
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "1h 3m 6s 0h 13m 30s 0h 15m 12s"
```